# Rapid random number generating function in C

Tags: c, random

I'm trying to make a random number generator that produces many new random numbers very quickly.  I have tried srand(time(NULL)) but since I'm trying to generate many number quickly this won't work.  Next I tried this:

```
int main()
{
    seed_plus=time(NULL);    
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<10;i++)
    {
        double R=ran(seed_plus);
        printf("%lf\n",R);
        seed_plus=seed_plus+1;
    }
}
double ran (int seed_plus)
{

    srand(seed_plus);
    double random_number = (double)random()/(double)RAND_MAX;
    return(random_number);
}
```

This works, but I would like to have "seed_plus=seed_plus+1" contained within the "ran" function.  When I move that statement inside the function I get many of the same "random" number, which leads me to believe that seed_plus is not being saved to memory since it is not the value being returned by the function?

I'm pretty new to C, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you seeding the random number generator every time?

Comment: **side note**: To numbers in the range [M, N] you should use `M + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (N - M + 1) + 1)`, read: [How can I get random integers in a certain range?](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html) your `M = 0` and `N = RAND_MAX`

Comment: Hi, you must accept an answer by clicking the `V` at their left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have to call `srand` one time, after that, all next calls to `random` will return different numbers each time.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to seed the random number generator every time you need a random number.  Just simplify your code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

double ran(void)
{
    return (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
}

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%f\n", ran());
}
```

Comment: @user2544213 - Then you should go into politics.